# Extract only a specific file from a zipped archive to a given directory

Tags: zip

I need to extract a single file from a ZIP file which I know the path to. Is there a command like the following:

```
unzip -d . myarchive.zip path/to/zipped/file.txt
```

Unfortunately, the above command extracts and recreates the entire path to the file at `./path/to/zipped/file.txt`. Is there a way for me to simply pull the file out into a specified directory?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

You can extract just the text to standard output with the `-p` option:

```
unzip -p myarchive.zip path/to/zipped/file.txt >file.txt
```

This won't extract the metadata (date, permissions, …), only the file contents (obviously, it only works for regular files, not symlinks, devices, directories...). That's the price to pay for the convenience of not having to move the file afterwards.

Alternatively, mount the archive as a directory and just copy the file. With [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/):

```
mountavfs
cp -p ~/.avfs"$PWD/myarchive.zip#"/path/to/zipped/file.txt .
```

Or with [fuse-zip](https://bitbucket.org/agalanin/fuse-zip):

```
mkdir myarchive.d
fuse-zip myarchive.zip myarchive.d
cp -p myarchive.d/path/to/zipped/file.txt .
fusermount -u myarchive.d; rmdir myarchive.d
```

Comment: Will it work for binary files, say a `jar` file?

Comment: @TKKocheran: Jar files are zips, so the unzip and fuse-zip methods will obviously work. The AVFS method also works, because AVFS guesses the format based on file names and knows about `.jar`; if your file is named differently you might need to tell AVFS to use its zip handler, e.g. `~/.avfs$PWD/foo.apk#uzip/META-INF`.

Comment: actually, I meant extracting a JAR/binary file from a ZIP archive. I haven't had the chance to test it out yet, can you see any issues using the first command above to extract binary files?

Comment: @TKKocheran: There's no problem, `-p` extracts the file as-is (`-c` does text conversion).

Comment: I think the answer of @Myles is more elegant, because it doesn't require output redirection and it preserves file attributes.

Answer (score 244):

```
unzip -j "myarchive.zip" "in/archive/file.txt" -d "/path/to/unzip/to"
```

Enter full path for zipped file, not just the filename. Be sure to keep the structure as seen from within the zip file.

This will extract the single file `file.txt` in `myarchive.zip` to `/path/to/unzip/to/file.txt`.

---

`-j`: junk paths. The archive's directory structure is not recreated; all files are deposited in the extraction directory (by default, the current one)

`-d`: An optional directory to which to extract files.

https://www.mankier.com/1/unzip

---

**Multiple files:**

```
unzip -j myarchive.zip in/archive/file.txt another/file.ext -d /path/to/unzip/to
```

---

**Entire Sub-directory**

```
unzip -j archive.zip "sub/dir/*" -d "dest/dir"
```

Comment: It doesn't handle the case where you want the generated filename to be different.

Comment: the "-j" paramter: junk paths. The archive's directory structure is not recreated; all files are deposited in the extraction directory (by default, the current one). the "-d" parameter: extract files into exdir

Comment: @OlegVaskevich, the question doesn't request target filename to be different

Comment: FYI to find out the path of files in zip, use `less`: https://superuser.com/questions/216617/view-list-of-files-in-zip-archive-on-linux

Comment: Some unzip binaries don't have the -d flag. I won't work in every linux

Comment: unzip accepts wildcard, so to **unzip sub-directory**: `unzip -j archive.zip "sub/dir/*" -d "dest/dir"`

Comment: @YiboYang or `mc` ;)

Comment: Thanks guys updated the original answer to include some of these!

Answer (score 54):

Simpler version:

```
unzip ARCHIVE_NAME PATH_OF_FILE_INSIDE_ARCHIVE
```

This will recreate `PATH_OF_FILE_INSIDE_ARCHIVE` in current directory but only extracts specified file.

To list all files in a Zip archive:

```
unzip -l ARCHIVE_NAME
```

Comment: This works with wildcards too, at least in CentOS - e.g. `unzip foo.zip *.bar`

Comment: this is all i needed. very succinct. don't really see any benefit in using other methods unless you need to extract many files at once.

Answer (score 15):

**On macOS**, which by default uses [Info-Zip](http://www.info-zip.org/)

First list off the files to find what you want

```
unzip -l my.zip
```

Then extract file from the archive

```
unzip my.zip annoying/path/to/file/in/zip
```

Combine with -p for stdout

```
unzip -p my.zip annoying/path/to/file/in/zip >./file
```

or -j for extracting to the current directory (discard junk path)

```
unzip -j my.zip annoying/path/to/file/in/zip
```

with -d you can specify to create an arbitrary directory

```
unzip -d /path/to/dir my.zip annoying/path/to/file/in/zip
```

If you want the file in the `-d` directory you probably want to combine it with the `-j` option.

Answer (score 5):

## simple use:

```
unzip zipfile.zip path/inside/zip/file.txt
```

**and it will inflate the file.**

```
$ unzip -l ./../html.zip | grep wp-config

     3328  07-22-2019 15:10   html/wp-config.php

     2898  01-07-2019 23:30   html/wp-config-sample.php

$ unzip ./../html.zip html/wp-config.php

     Archive:  ./../html.zip
     inflating: html/wp-config.php

$ ls -lrth

     total 4.0K
     drwxr-sr-x 2 apache apache 4.0K Jul 26 14:41 html

$ ls -lrth html/*

     total 4.0K
     -rw-rw-rw- 1 apache apache 3.3K Jul 22 15:10 wp-config.php
```

Comment: Can also add the `-d outpath` argument to specify where the file is put in.

Comment: And the `-j` argument to avoid the compressed paths

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restore the file's metadata from the archive, be able to restore files of any type (including symlinks) and with arbitrary names, and also choose the new name of the file, you could use libarchive's `bsdtar` (which also supports ZIP format archives) instead of `unzip` as:

```
bsdtar -nqvvxpf file.zip -'s/.*/newname/S' some/dir/originalname
```

Note: like in `unzip`, the `some/dir/originalname` there is taken as a shell wildcard pattern. So if the path of archive member you want to extract does contain `*`, `?`, `\` or `[` characters, you'll need to escape them as in:

```
bsdtar -nqvvxpf file.zip -'s/.*/newname/S' 'som[?]/dir/[*]riginalname'
```

or:

```
bsdtar -nqvvxpf file.zip -'s/.*/newname/S' 'som\?/dir/\*riginalname'
```

if the archive member is called `som?/dir/*riginalname`.

Note that that approach would work with any of the archive formats supported by libarchive, not just zip.

Answer (score 0):

Extract to a relative dir

```
unzip -j -d relativedir archive.zip path/in/archive/file.ext
```

Extract to the current dir

```
unzip -j -d . archive.zip path/in/archive/file.ext
```

Extract to absolute dir

```
unzip -j -d /absolutedir archive.zip path/in/archive/file.ext
```

Answer (score -1):

```
unzip myarchive.zip `zipinfo -2 myarchive.zip | head -1`
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).