# Extract specified types from a zip file

Tags: zip

I have a big zip archive and I want to extract only `.mp3` files that are located in `sites/default/files/` to `mymp3` directory. How can I achieve it?

Comment: @DopeGhoti I didn't try anything if you know how can I do it please provide your answer, extract `sites/default/files/*.mp3` files form zip file

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14120/extract-only-a-specific-file-from-a-zipped-archive-to-a-given-directory

Comment: @bodhi.zazen you just search the google and paste it here ? :D  , read the question first please,  files not file ;)

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution, you can do it with

```
unzip yourzipfile.zip 'sites/default/files/*.mp3' -d mymp3
```

Comment: You better put the filename wildcard into quotes, else you'll get problems if an mp3 already exists in the local path.