# List files in a zipped archive within a zipped archive

Tags: macos, zip

So far this thread ([Extract only a specific file from a zipped archive to a given directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14120/extract-only-a-specific-file-from-a-zipped-archive-to-a-given-directory/361877#361877?newreg=45b38a41ef0c43b9afe29769f481227c)) has helped me tremendously as I was able to generate a file list of all the files in the archive, using:

```
unzip -l X201SC21041496-Z01-F002.zip
```

and even look into a specific file that was also compressed, using:

```
unzip -p X201SC21041496-Z01-F002.zip X201SC21041496-Z01-F002/rawdata/G_M0_2.fq.gz | gunzip -c | head
```

However, there are also other .zip files in the first .zip file and I want to get a list of that and then potentially look at some of those files without having to unzip the entire thing. I have tried several things:

```
unzip -p X201SC21041496-Z01-F002.zip X201SC21041496-Z01-F002/Result_X201SC21041496-Z01-F002_Canis_lupus_familiaris.zip | unzip -l
```

But then I just get referred to the unzip manual (which, to be fair, I need). Or:

```
unzip -pl X201SC21041496-Z01-F002.zip X201SC21041496-Z01-F002/Result_X201SC21041496-Z01-F002_Canis_lupus_familiaris.zip
```

Which seemed to list stuff, but then just spit out garbage.
I have now resorted to extracting the archive from the archive to my external (using unzip with the -j and -d flags as suggested above, see below) and hoping that I'll be able to navigate that archive from there. But, there surely is a better way?

```
unzip -j "X201SC21041496-Z01-F002.zip" "X201SC21041496-Z01-F002/Result_X201SC21041496-Z01-F002_Canis_lupus_familiaris.zip" -d "/Volumes/Elements_of_Elise/Postdoc_VI_UU/Qingkang/"
```

Apologies in advance if I am not using the correct terminology or notation. Very much a rookie, but trying to learn! I did spend a considerably time searching for the answer, but here we are. I am using my terminal on a Macbook pro, BigSur 11.3.1.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I’m aware, this isn’t possible with `unzip` because it can’t read archives from standard input; however `jar`, a tool in the Java Development Kits, can:

```
unzip -p X201SC21041496-Z01-F002.zip X201SC21041496-Z01-F002/Result_X201SC21041496-Z01-F002_Canis_lupus_familiaris.zip |
jar tv
```